# algorithm - merging similar lines into one

Tags: algorithm, line, hough-transform

I am using the Hough transform algorithm do determine lines.
Right now I am just taking the peak values from the matrix that are over a certain threshold, but I am getting a lot of duplicate lines that i want to merge into one.

This is the code for finding peaks:

```
 int prevVal = INT_MIN;

const int NOISE = 110;

enum
{
    Ascending,
    Descending
} direction = Ascending;

std::vector<Peak>peaks;

for (int x = 0; x < m_matrixWidth - 1; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < m_matrixHeight - 1; y++) {

        double currentValue = m_matrix[x*m_matrixHeight + y];

        if (prevVal < currentValue) {  
            direction = Ascending;
        }
        else if (prevVal > currentValue) { 
            if (direction != Descending) { 
                if (currentValue > NOISE) {
                    Peak peak(x, y, currentValue);
                    peaks.push_back(peak);
                    std::cout << "peak at index " << x*m_matrixHeight + y << ": " << prevVal << std::endl;
                }
                direction = Descending;
            }
        }

        prevVal = currentValue;

    }
}


return peaks;
```

This is how it looks:
[image]

If anyone knows, thanks.

Comment: Does clusterization in rho-theta space work for you?

Comment: Find the slanted bounding box of the outline, this will be much more effective than damned Hough lines.

Comment: @Yves Daoust i have to use the Hough transform

Comment: My downvotes to your teacher ;-)

Comment: Do you want to merge "duplicate" lines, or "similar" lines?

Comment: @Jim Mischel simialr lines, the ones that differ by just a few degrees and are in the same location